# Updating item by react useState hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-functional-component

I am new to functional components in react and I have a problem with updating data. Here is my function that just sets actual data to a variable, finds the actual item and updates it. The problem is that finds the actual item correctly but doesn't update the data. Data is just useState with an array of elements of course.

```
  const onEditElement = (elementId) => {
    let elements = data;
    let actualElement = elements.find((x) => x.id === elementId);
    actualElement = { value: "newValue" };
    setData(elements);
};
```

this is how data looks like:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([{id: 1, value: "initial"}]);
```

How can I solve this problem and what is causing it?

Comment: you should write the whole part of your code. mention the data structure and the rendering part

Comment: I think you might have to create a clone of your array and call setData() with the clone, otherwise the change won't be detected.

Comment: I think you are setting the same data to the state. Does your state looks like this? `const [data, setData] = useState([...]);`. Try setting something different, I guess the elements you found.

Comment: @AdriSolid yes this is exactly how my state looks like

Comment: Try this: `setData([{ id: 1, ...actualElement }]);`. Always assuming you will have just one item in your array state.

Comment: @AdriSolid I have many items in array of course, otherwise I will not use an array but an object if there would be only one item right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to update the elements array by changing the found object in the `onEditElement()` function that this code doesn't work (read the mistake parts below to find out why this happening).

you should change the function like this:

```js
const onEditElement = (elementId) => {
  let elements = [...data];
  let currentElementIndex = elements.findIndex((x) => x.id === elementId);
  if (currentElementIndex === -1) return;
  elements[currentElementIndex] = { id: elementId, value: "newValue" };
  // if you do elements[currentElementIndex].value = ... your data array will be mutated. then its better you do the way above
  setData(elements);
};
```

**Description**

1. Generally: in the `React Class Component` we were defining a state and we were updating that state using `setState({ key: value })`.
   in the `React Functional Component` we have a different approach. we can have multiple `useState`s and also we should update the whole thing when we use state setter. then, if we have `{ key1: value1, key2: value2 }` and we want to change the key1's value. we should put `{ key1: newValue1, key2: value2 }` in the state setter. we can do this with `setData((prvData) => ({ ...prevData, key1: newValue1 }))`
2. Your Case: you have an array of objects. it does not matter you are using Class or Functional component. suppose you have an array in your `this.state` data key in the Class Component like `this.state = { data: [] }`. you should put whole array with updated items in the `setState` function like `setState({ data: WHOLE_ARRAY_WITH_UPDATED_ITEMS })`. also you should do this in Functional Component and do `setData(WHOLE_ARRAY_WITH_UPDATED_ITEMS)`

**The Mistakes**:

1. you should use spread operator to prevent mutate the `data` array.
2. you are defining new variable called `actualElement` and you are updating this variable and think it should change the elements array but it is an invidual object that has no connection to `elements` array. this variable is separated from elements array and changing it won't cause an effect on elements array. you should find actualElement index and update elements array directly using the current editing index somehow I did in the code above.

Comment: This one works! Thank you very much, but I still don't fully understand my mistake, can you please describe it better? What is wrong with my code?

Comment: @Sowam I add a description. read it and tell me if it is still ambiguous.

Comment: Yes it is perfect now, thank you so much again :)